# How can I call an http backend but not wait for response?

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

I have a backend api call that takes ages to respond.  Like maybe 10 minutes.  It does, however, publish progress updates via signalr.  Putting the signalr bit to one side, I need a way to make an http post but not wait for the response.  Fire and forget. 
To expand on this, I’m calling the api in an ngrx effect.  Once the call is made, I want to kick off a different action that my reducer will handle.
Is there an rxjs operation that could do this?

Answer (score 1):

It depends.

Does your server keep continuing the work even if the http connection is severed? In that case you can [abort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/abort) from the client side (given that your used HTTP library supports this). If it mostly completes fast but sometimes takes 10 minutes you could also employ a `.timeout()` on the Rx stream to stop listening to it.

An other solution would be to have the http call be resolved without waiting for the answer. This can be done either using `.toPromise()` and not `awaiting` this or `.subscribe()` without any handlers. But these resources would be allocated and keep running in the background without any option to do anything with these.

Answer (score 0):

You `subscribe` to your HTTP calls to trigger them, and use a callback to do something once the call is done.

But you can simply make your call in a function, and don't wait for your HTTP call to end :

```js
doSmthSync() {
  this.myService.myCall(...myArgs).subscribe(response => {/* Do smth async */});
  // Do something here that will be made without waiting for the end pf the call
}
```